# class variable cannot be found within the nested VBA loop

Tags: excel, vba

My code finds user defined values in an active worksheet, selects, copies them, and then paste them into a separate worksheet. When I incorporate a loop to iterate over a list of values and copy the results into separate tabs the code breaks. The error Object variable not set (Error 91).

Any thoughts?

```
Sub copy_paste_sheet_names3()

'declare variables

Dim mainworkBook As Workbook
Set mainworkBook = ActiveWorkbook

Dim sheet_name As String

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim SelectCells As Range
Dim xcell As Object
Set ws = Worksheets("MasterData")

'check each cell in the specific worksheet if the criteria is matching

For i = 1 To mainworkBook.Sheets.Count


        sheet_name = mainworkBook.Sheets(i).Name
        
        For Each xcell In ws.UsedRange.Cells
        
        If xcell.Value = sheet_name Then
        If SelectCells Is Nothing Then
        Set SelectCells = Range(xcell.Address)
        Else
        Set SelectCells = Union(SelectCells, Range(xcell.Address))
        End If
        End If
        
        Next
        
        'select the cells with specified value
        SelectCells.EntireRow.Select
        SelectCells.EntireRow.Copy
        
        Sheets(sheet_name).Select
        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ws.Select
     

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you get the error? Why don't you dim `xcell` as a range?

Comment: Your ranges are unqualified, which means they will always be looking at `ActiveSheet` instead of the sheet you think.

Comment: `Range(xcell.Address)` is the same as `xcell` , but with an added bug where you'll get the wrong range if the active sheet is not the one containing `xcell`  Also -need to reset `SelectCells` to Nothing between sheets.  And test for `If Not SelectCells Is Nothing` before trying to run the copy.

Comment: the code breaks at SelectCells.EntireRow.Select

Comment: If `SelectCells` is Nothing then you can't copy it.

Comment: `xcell` should be declared as a `Range` because you are referring to cells